How to Add JVM Arguments in Azure Application Service?
I have a Spring Boot App running in Azure asapp service, and I would like to add a JVM Arg (-Dspring.profiles.active=dev)
I already tried it using as environmental variable in azure as mentioned in different tutorials, but it has not been read.
Does anyone has a working solution?

Did you try adding it as JAVA_OPTS or languageWorkers__java__arguments with value -Dspring.profiles.active=dev in App Settings of Azure App Service?

As mentioned in MSDOC, arguments can be provided to the JVM by using the application settings:
1. JAVA_OPTS
2. languageWorkers__java__arguments

I have created a Spring boot application and deployed to Azure App Service.
Local Response:
2024-09-27T14:42:27.100+05:30  INFO 19928 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.11 with PID 19928
2024-09-27T14:42:27.100+05:30  INFO 19928 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2024-09-27T14:42:29.641+05:30  INFO 19928 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-09-27T14:42:29.674+05:30  INFO 19928 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-09-27T14:42:29.674+05:30  INFO 19928 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.30]
2024-09-27T14:42:29.782+05:30  INFO 19928 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-09-27T14:42:29.798+05:30  INFO 19928 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2530 ms
2024-09-27T14:42:30.884+05:30  INFO 19928 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
2024-09-27T14:42:30.931+05:30  INFO 19928 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 4.977 seconds (process running for 6.198)
Active profile: dev

App Service logs before configuring the Active Profile, web app used the default profile:
.. com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.12 with PID 94 (/home/site/wwwroot/app.jar started by root in /home/site/wwwroot)
.. com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
.. o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
.. w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 23576 ms
.. o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
.. com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 50.272 seconds (process running for 115.141)


Configured the JVM Argument -Dspring.profiles.active=dev using JAVA_OPTS under App Service=>Settings=>Environment Variables=>App Settings:

The Active profile set to dev can be seen in the App Service logs:
2024-09-27T08:34:59.826Z  INFO 93 --- [main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.12 with PID 93 (/home/site/wwwroot/app.jar started by root in /home/site/wwwroot)
2024-09-27T08:34:59.972Z  INFO 93 --- [main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2024-09-27T08:35:23.825Z  INFO 93 --- [main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-09-27T08:35:25.304Z  INFO 93 --- [main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 24323 ms
2024-09-27T08:35:37.365Z  INFO 93 --- [main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
2024-09-27T08:35:37.674Z  INFO 93 --- [main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 55.119 seconds (process running for 92.024)
2024-09-27T08:35:39.475Z  INFO 93 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-09-27T08:35:39.511Z  INFO 93 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms



Thank you! Looks like it suddenly works. We did the same yesterday but have not re-deployed the app. Instead we restartet the container, is that maybe the reason why it hasnt worked yesterday?

Yes, possible. Did you make any other changes in your project?

its working great with redeployment. Thank you! How do you deploy your app are you using any CI/DI Pipeline or via commandline and AzureCLI?
